# After i click on the back button on the appBar ,it doesnt go back to the previous screen

Tags: flutter

This is the code i have for it
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfRGo.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0Gi.png)

Tried to make it go back to the previous screen but for some reason it says: I/flutter (14365): Another exception was thrown: Cannot install a MaterialPageRoute<dynamic> after disposing it. I didnt dispose of it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reinitialize MaterialPageRoute to solve this problem

Here is an example:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MenuItem {
  final String name;
  final dynamic route;

  MenuItem({required this.name, required this.route});
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<MenuItem> menuItems = [
    MenuItem(name: "Menu 1", route: const MenuScreen(title: "Menu 1")), //here
    MenuItem(name: "Menu 2", route: const MenuScreen(title: "Menu 2")) //here
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Home Screen")),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: List.generate(
            menuItems.length,
            (index) => ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => menuItems[index].route, //here
                      ));
                },
                child: Text(menuItems[index].name))),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MenuScreen({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MenuScreen> createState() => _MenuScreenState();
}

class _MenuScreenState extends State<MenuScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        leading: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.navigate_before_sharp,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: const SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```